# Angular theming palette setup with custom names and colors

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, theming

I'm trying to create custom theming palette with unique names and colors in Angular application project with using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/), or maybe even without using components library.

According Angular Material first I followed [Theming your Angular Material app](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) and created `my-theme.scss` in `src` folder directory like this:

```
@import "~@angular/material/theming";

@include mat-core();
```

I tried with name from `_theming.scss`:

```
$my-theme-my-name1: mat-palette($mat-green, 300, 400, 500, 700);
$my-theme-my-name2: mat-palette($mat-amber, 300, 400, 500, 700);
```

then:

```
$my-theme: mat-palette(
  $my-theme-my-name1,
  $my-theme-my-name2
);

@include angular-material-theme($my-theme);
```

then I add path `src/my-theme.scss` in `angular.json` like this:

```
"styles": [
{
   "input": "src/my-theme.scss"
},
"src/styles.scss"
],
```

and use name in `<button my-theme-my-name1>My button</button>` but button does not changes color.

`styles.scss` includes `@import '~@angular/material/theming';` by default with installation of library, maybe I have to change something only in `styles.scss` without creating `my-theme.scss` and using from `_theming.scss`, I'm not sure exactly how, but something like:

```
$my-theme-my-name1: my-palette(#fff, 300, 400, 500, 700);
```

because it looks like, that I'm doing something wrong way, colors does not changed and `ng serve` throws error with adding  `src/my-theme.scss`  to `angular.json`:

> An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
> lstat '..\src\my-theme.scss' See "..\ng-hZt0fz\angular-errors.log" for
> further details.

```
[error] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '...\src\my-theme.scss'
    at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1728:7)
    at ...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\styles.js:44:35
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.getStylesConfig (...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\styles.js:35:76)
    at ...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:91:23
    at generateWebpackConfig (...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:45:49)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async generateBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:136:20)
    at async Object.generateI18nBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:77:20)
    at async setup (...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:87:47)
```

Comment: Have you tried to import it into globas.scss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `$my-theme-my-name1` is a sass variable, adding this directly to the button as an attribute will not style your button. (You cannot reference sass variables in HTML or TS).

Here is how you can style your own components.
Create a custom selector (id or class) for your button and add theme colors to it.

Example

```
/*...necessary imports*/
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $candy-app-primary,
    accent: $candy-app-accent,
    warn: $candy-app-warn,  
  )
));

@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme); //This will make sure to style material components    
.my-custom-btn {
  background-color: mat-color($candy-app-primary);
  color: mat-color($candy-app-primary, default-contrast);
}
```

Now add the class `my-custom-btn` to the button `<button class="my-custom-btn">My button</button>`

The above is just an example, It is recommended to create your own mixin for styling your own components.

And coming to the error, this clearly means that the file **my-theme.scss** is deleted, removed or renamed.

Comment: Hello, sorry for late replay So, if I get it right .my-custom-btn then should be used inside the component .scss

Comment: Actually, you can create `component-theme.scss` and add only theme styles into it then import it in the global theming file, And define all remaining styles in a normal component stylesheet [as suggested by angular material](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components)